# Como verificar a existência de um arquivo e a quantidade de linhas escritas em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Qual a melhor forma para verificar se o arquivo é existente e a quantidade de linhas dentro do arquivo.

Comment: O que você já tentou e por que não deu certo?

Comment: Só usei try e except, mas não sei se é o melhor a ser feito. Pois estou fazendo um programa crítico, então devo tomar o máximo de cuidados para evitar falhas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o `is_file` do `pathlib.Path` pra descobrir se o arquivo existe.

Pra contar as linhas, basta descobrir o `len` da leitura do arquivo:

```
from pathlib import Path

caminho = Path('./arquivo.txt')

if caminho.is_file():
    print('Arquivo existe!')
    with open(caminho, 'r') as f:
        n_linhas = len(f.readlines())
    print('Ele tem {} linhas.'.format(n_linhas))
else:
    print('Arquivo inexistente :(')
```

Comment: Ocorre um erro no caminho, e ao usar len retorna "none" mesmo que o arquivo esteja escrito.

Comment: Qual erro? Esse caminho é um caminho no meu computador. Talvez você tenha que modificá-lo pra achar o seu arquivo. Não consigo testar pro Windows no momento, mas funciona aqui.

Comment: Sim modifiquei para meu caminho no linux, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Qual é o seu caminho?

Comment: /home/filipe/Proj/data/config.dat

Comment: Pode ser feito com o modulo `os` facilmente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259382/pythonic-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists

Comment: Estranho, não sei por que não funcionaria. Consegue dar `cat`, `wc -l /home/filipe/Proj/data/config.dat`, etc? Pode tentar com o `os`, como na sugestão acima.